# Effecting the instance fields of one class with the instance fields of another

Tags: java

I want to clarify beforehand that I am only interested in programming from a hobbyist perspective and have no education regarding programming nor do I have any professional experience.

I am trying to figure out how to affect the instance fields of one class with the instance fields of another. Here is an example of what I'm trying to figure out:

```
//Main Class
class Main
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {

        Class1 instance1 = new Class1(1);
        Class2 instance2 = new Class2(1);

    }

    public void method1()
    {
        // code to add the class1 instance field value class1Num1 to Class2 instance field value class2Num1
        // at least cobine the two values in one variable that is usable in Main
    }
}

//Class1
class Class1
{
    int class1Num1;

    public Class1(int num1)
    {
        class1Num1 = num1;
    }
}

//Class2
class Class2
{
    int class2Num1;

    public Class2(int num1)
    {
        class2Num1 = num1;
    }
}
```

Ultimately I want to know how I could get `class2Num1` and add it to `class1Num1` in the Main class. I mean want to change the value of `class1Num1` via a method so that later in my program when `class1Num1` is referenced, the value returned is 2 (class1Num1 +class2Num1). How would I write a method to do that and what class or classes would I have to write this in? This may be an incredibly simple task I realize but I can't seem to figure this out.

Based on responses it look as if getter and setter methods are the way to go however, based on the examples I have seen so far it looks as though instance1 and instance2 are having to be passed as arguments in the Main class method that combines the two numbers. Is there a way that I could write a method so that it targets the instance that calls the method? Here is an example:

```
//this method is being called in Main
instance1.method(int class2){
    int a = getClass1Num1(); 
// ^ how could I target the instance calling this method here?
// 
    int b = class2.getClass2num1();
    int c = a +b;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's better to use **private fields** and **getter** and **setter** methods

> **Class1** is as follows

```
    public class Class1 {

    //fields
    private int class1Num1;

    //getter
    public int getClass1Num1() {
        return class1Num1;
    }

    //setter
    public void setClass1Num1(int class1Num1) {
        this.class1Num1 = class1Num1;
    }
}
```

> **Class2** is as follows

```
public class Class2 {

    //fields
    private int class2Num1;

    //getter 
    public int getClass2Num1() {
        return class2Num1;
    }

    //setter
    public void setClass2Num1(int class2Num1) {
        this.class2Num1 = class2Num1;
    }
}
```

> **Main Class** is as follows

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        //Set class1Num1
        Class1 instance1 = new Class1();
        instance1.setClass1Num1(1);

        //Set class2Num1
        Class2 instance2 = new Class2();
        instance2.setClass2Num1(1);

        //add class1Num1 + class2Num1
        int sum = instance1.getClass1Num1() + instance2.getClass2Num1();

        //Set sum into class1Num1 of instance1
        instance1.setClass1Num1(sum);

        //Printing class1Num1 (2)
        System.out.println(instance1.getClass1Num1());

    }
}
```

Comment: Is there a way I could do this so that i can target the num1 of the instance calling the method without having to explicitly pass that instance as an argument? For example: class1.mathod(class2){int a = class1(the instance calling the method).num1; int b = class2.getClass2num1; int c = a +b;}

Answer (score 0):

a good object oriented way to do that would be to include a getter method to return the instance variable of your classes. Eg you should add a method like this to your Class1 and Class2 :

```
public int getInstanceVar() {
    return class1Num1;  // Or class2Num1 in Class2
}
```

Then in your main class you can call this method from your newly created Class1 // Class2 objects, eg :

```
int result = instance1.getInstanceVar() + instance2.getInstanceVar();
```

Comment: The best object-oriented way is to make fields of the class final and of course that fields must not change at all !!
I mean The best object-oriented way is to make classes immutable.

Comment: @Mehrdad I guess making immutable classes depends on the context & requirements. I don't think the OP requires it here. Not gonna argue over best OO practices here, just tried to provide a simple solution that can be easily understood by an apprentice. Anyway, answer updated and replaced "best" with "good" :)

Comment: Yes, you're right it completely depends on the context. thank you for editing.

Comment: This does work well for my application as I will be making multiple instances of my classes and will need to be changing their field values on a constant basis. I appreciate all of the community's help here. I know most if not all of you are professionals and I appreciate you taking the time to answer my questions.